# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, spring-test-mvc

Getting error  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()`

In `pom.xml`, I have mentioned 2 dependencies

```
<!--For DispatcherServlet-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<!--For Spring JUnit + mockito test-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code in My Test class

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/user/login").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());
```

For more reference stacktrace are,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:166)
    at com.payex.test.UserControllerTest.isValidLoginTest(UserControllerTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Answer (score 2):

You use different version of the javax.servlet for testing. The [getStatus()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getStatus--) method was only added in Servlet version 3.0, you have version 2.5 specified in the JUnit testing section in your pom.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use a Servlet 3.1 container as a bare minimum however it looks like you use mockito 2.21 which at most uses a Servlet 2.5 container. I do not think that will work.